# Passing Array of Structures from C#(.NET Core) to C++(unamnaged)

Tags: c#, c++, .net-core, pinvoke, marshalling

So I've read the documentation and countless examples online how to marshal array of structures. I've marshalled array of int's, I've marshalled structures, but now I'm completely stuck and can't get it to work no matter what I've try. Been stuck on it for over a day now.

Structure/class, tried as both

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public class SaveDetails
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string Log;
    public FILETIME FileTime;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public bool Saved;
}
```

Pinvoke and call delegate

```
public class LogSaveFiles : IDisposable
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi,CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private delegate Status DLogSaveFiles([ In, Out] SaveDetails[] logsToSave, string destinationPath);
    private static DLogSaveFiles _dLogSaveFiles;

    private IntPtr PLogSaveFiles { get; set; }
    public bool LogSaveFilesAvailable => PLogSaveFiles != IntPtr.Zero;

    public LogSaveFiles(Importer importer)
    {
        if (importer.dllLibraryPtr!= IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            PLogSaveFiles = Importer.GetProcAddress(importer.dllLibrary, "LogSaveFiles");
        }
    }

    public Status SaveFiles(SaveDetails[] logsToSave,string destinationPath)
    {
        Status result = Status.FunctionNotAvailable;

        if (LogSaveFilesAvailable)
        {
            _dLogSaveFiles = (DLogSaveFiles)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(PLogSaveFiles, typeof(DLogSaveFiles));

            result = _dLogSaveFiles(logsToSave, destinationPath);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

Call

```
      private void SaveLogs()
    {
        var logsToSave = new[]{
            new SaveDetails{
                FileTime = new FILETIME {dwHighDateTime = 3,dwLowDateTime = 5},
                Log = LogTypes.logDeviceLog,
                Saved = true},
            new SaveDetails{
                FileTime = new FILETIME {dwHighDateTime = 1,dwLowDateTime = 2},
                Log = LogTypes.logDeviceLog,
                Saved = false}
             };

        var pathToSave = "C:\\Logs";
        _logSaveFiles.SaveFiles(logsToSave, pathToSave);
    }
```

c++ exposed call

```
    typedef struct _LOG_SAVE_DETAILS
{
    LPTSTR      szLog;
    FILETIME    fromFileTime;
    BOOL        bSaved;
} LOG_SAVE_DETAILS, *PLOG_SAVE_DETAILS;


/* Function definitions */

ULY_STATUS _API LogSaveFiles (PLOG_SAVE_DETAILS   ppLogs [],
                                         LPCTSTR                szDestinationPath);
```

Path to destination gets passed properly, but array of structures never goes through resulting in access violation when trying to access it. At first I thought it was issue with LPTSTR not going through properly but I've implemented other calls with it on its own and succeeded marshalling it through.

I've read everything on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-data-with-platform-invoke , it all indicates that my approach is correct, but it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure, the C part is using unicode right?

Comment: Other problem: how does the C++ knows how many `ppLogs` are present? Normally you would put a `\0` element as the last one, but your aren't doing it, nor are you passing the array length.

Comment: @xanatos yeh its unicode, and C++ expects array to be null terminated, which I've tried as well but that didnt work. ( that is only checked during execution, when it goes through array until it finds null). I cannot  edit c++ api.

Comment: Think before you code!!!  I started with c language on unix and read the entire Unix manual a lot of times.  I learned a lot from understanding the standard unix strucutures. Arrays need to either be terminate with null or include a length before the array. Your first issue is having a LPWStr at the beginning of the structure.It is really a int16[] terminated with a '\0'.So to find the beginning of the FILETIME you have to first find the null in the LPWStr.And you can't just look for '\0' it must be in the first byte of the int16 and not the second byte.  Easy to be done in c, not easy in c#.

Comment: @jdweng No, `sizeof(LPWSTR)` is fixed, it's just the size of a pointer.

Comment: David : Where does it say that a string is a pointer????

Comment: @jdweng Er, that's what `LPTSTR` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution: C side change `PLOG_SAVE_DETAILS ppLogs []` to `LOG_SAVE_DETAILS ppLogs []`, then C#-side change `public class SaveDetails` to `public struct SaveDetails`.

Marshaling array of objects seems to be difficult (I wasn't able to do it). Marshaling array of structs works. An alternative is to do the marshaling manually, but it is a pain.

The "pain" of manual marshaling (only modified lines of code):

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private delegate Status DLogSaveFiles(IntPtr[] logsToSave, string destinationPath);
```

and then

```
public Status SaveFiles(SaveDetails[] logsToSave, string destinationPath)
{
    Status result = Status.FunctionNotAvailable;

    if (LogSaveFilesAvailable)
    {
        if (_dLogSaveFiles == null)
        {
            _dLogSaveFiles = (DLogSaveFiles)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(PLogSaveFiles, typeof(DLogSaveFiles));
        }

        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SaveDetails));

        IntPtr basePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr[] ptrs = new IntPtr[logsToSave.Length + 1];

        try
        {
            basePtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size * logsToSave.Length);

            for (int i = 0; i < logsToSave.Length; i++)
            {
                ptrs[i] = IntPtr.Add(basePtr, (i * size));
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(logsToSave[i], ptrs[i], false);
            }

            result = _dLogSaveFiles(ptrs, destinationPath);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (basePtr != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < logsToSave.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (ptrs[i] != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        Marshal.DestroyStructure(ptrs[i], typeof(SaveDetails));
                    }
                }

                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(basePtr);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Important: this is a marshaler C#->C++. The C++ mustn't modify the received array in any way or there will be a memory leak.**

Comment: I cannot change c++ exposed method as that is part of huge framework used in many places,

Comment: @AistisTaraskevicius I can write some ad-hoc marshaling. Does the C++-side modified the array? Because if not it is much simpler.

Comment: c++ does not modify the array, it just uses values stored in it

Comment: @AistisTaraskevicius Manual marshaling posted. The marshaler adds an "empty" element at the end of the array so that the C++ code knows when to stop.

Comment: sorry for slow reply, was away for the weekend, will have a look tomorrow morning !